Contradiction and Unfair Punishment?
In Surah 2:62 it states,

62 Indeed, those who believed and those who were Jews or Christians or Sabeans [before Prophet Muḥammad (ﷺ)] - those [among them] who believed in Allāh and the Last Day and did righteousness - will have their reward with their Lord, and no fear will there be concerning them, nor will they grieve.
— Surat al-Baqarah 62

However in 5:72 it says

72 They have certainly disbelieved who say, "Allāh is the Messiah, the son of Mary" while the Messiah has said, "O Children of Israel, worship Allāh, my Lord and your Lord." Indeed, he who associates others with Allāh - Allāh has forbidden him Paradise, and his refuge is the Fire. And there are not for the wrongdoers any helpers.
— Surat al-Ma'idah 72

So in the first verse, it says that Christians will go to Heaven, but in the second verse it says that they won't. On top of this, the second verse states that "he who associates others with Allah - Allah has forbidden him paradise."

This is two distinct questions that really should be asked separately. I have taken the liberty of removing the second question so that the first one might be addressed properly.
